# Stuck with a Sturm-Liouville problem: $((a+x)f'(x))' = - \lambda f(x)$, $f(0)=f(1)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Let $a>0$ be a constant positive number. I am stuck trying to solve the following regular Sturm-Liouville problem:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}((a+x)f'(x)) = -\lambda f(x),\qquad f(0)=f(1)=0$$

where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue. I need to find the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ and the corresponding $f(x)$.

**My attempt:**
According to Mathematica, the general solution of the ODE is:

$$f(x) = c_1 I_0(2\sqrt{-(a+x)\lambda}) + c_2 K_0(2\sqrt{-(a+x)\lambda})$$

where $I_0(x),K_0(x)$ are Bessel's modified functions of the first and second kind, respectively. However I cannot find a way to pick $c_1,c_2,\lambda$ so as to satisfy $f(0)=f(1)=0$, mainly because $K_0$ becomes complex and I don't know how to make it real! I am probably missing something obvious, but I keep obtaining that the only way to satisfy $f(0) = f(1)=0$ is to $c_{1,2}=0$, which of course violates the basic theorem of Sturm-Liouville theory (that a non-trivial solution must exist for regular problems).

Comment: Wolfram gives a different solution, one where the offending square root is non-negative; http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((a%2Bx)f%27(x))%27+%2B+lambda++f(x)%3D0

Comment: @Ranc There is still a minus sign under the square root. As soon as you make $\lambda$ positive, $K_0$ becomes complex.

Comment: Can't $c_1,c_2$ be complex?

Comment: @Ranc Of course. But $f(x)$ has to be real.

Comment: You have to find the values of $\lambda$ for which there exists a non-trivial solution such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Such values of $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Yes, I know. My issue is the analytical solution, which I cannot get.

Comment: Have you looked at the cases $\lambda < 0$?

Comment: Are there no non-trivial solutions with $\lambda > 0$? The physical problem I am solving does not make sense with $\lambda < 0$ (but I'll think about it)... If you can prove that $\lambda < 0$ for this Sturm-Liouville problem, then I'll have to rethink my model :P.